# How can I set default class name using selenium webdriver when two panel have same class name

Tags: eclipse, class, selenium, scrollbar

I am working on Scrolling the panel and in my system there are two panel and both have scrollbar with same Class name, so how Can I scroll down second panel using selenium webdriver?

Scrollbar Class Name : mCSB_draggerRail

I have wrote following codes for scrolling panel

driver.findElement(By.className("mCSB_draggerRail")).click();

But when I run the code it will scroll panel 1 and I want scroll Panel 2, so how can I scroll Panel 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow this simple steps::
(For Java)

Step 1: driver.findElement(By.xpath("xPath of main scroll")).click();

Step 2: driver.findElement(By.xpath("xPath of scrollbar")).click();

Step 3: Run Script

Note : Main Scroll is a button which perform scroll in scrollbar

Comment: nice..its really useful :)